# Mock Timezone in PhantomJS for Jasmine Test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, date, jasmine, phantomjs

Is it possible to mock a timezone in Jasmine to test a date object?

I have a function which takes A UTC time string and converts it to a date object.

Using "2016-01-16T07:29:59+0000", I want to be able to verify that when we are in PST we are observing 2016-01-**15 23:29:59** as the local date/time

I'd like to be able to switch this time zone back to GMT and then ensure that we observe 2016-01-**16 07:29:59** as the local date/time

(How) is this possible? (I am running my Jasmine spec through Grunt with phantomjs)

My function for reference:

```
utcDateStringToDateObject: function(dateString){
    return dateString.indexOf('+')>-1 ? new Date(dateString.split('+')[0]) : new Date(dateString);
}
```

Comment: Are you working with angular? If so you can create a factory called Date, which you then mock in Jasmine as you would mock anything. If not then same logic of using a factory applies.

Comment: @andyHaslt Unfortunately not. This is a backbone project. Cheers

Comment: Well you can always overwrite the Date function in an individual test. Otherwise how about https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex

Comment: Some additional info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone

Comment: What functionality are you trying to test here? What is the spec for your test?  Are you testing weather the browser is doing conversions correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I am using jasmine 3.4.0, one solution is to use the clock

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        jasmine.clock().install();
        // whenever new Date() occurs return the date below
        jasmine.clock().mockDate(new Date('2024-04-08T06:40:00'));
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    });
```

However, since my tests included timezones, I had to spyOn my service

```
it('should support work', () => {
        const mocked = moment.tz('2019-03-27 10:00:00', 'America/New_York');
        spyOn(spectator.service, 'getMoment').and.returnValue(mocked);
        const output = spectator.service.foo('bar');
        // My asserts
        expect(output.start.format(dateFormat)).toBe('2019-03-17T00:00:00-04:00');
        expect(output.end.format(dateFormat)).toBe('2019-03-23T23:59:59-04:00');
    });
```